# Saving values into array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if((i%2)==0)
    {
         System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

In the above coding instead of printing "i" values I need to save the values of "i" in array. How can I save the values in an array??

Comment: Just declare an array and pushing them to it helps ? What you have tried ?

Comment: Should `if(int i=0;i<10;i++)` be `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` ?

Comment: Sorry i mistakenly typed "if" instead of "for"...

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr=new int[10];
int j=0;    

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  if((i%2)==0)
  {
     arr[j]=i;
     j++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array like `int a[10];`
and then simply add the i value to the array by doing

```
a[1] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare array and assign value to it.

```
int a[] = new int[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   if((i%2)==0){
       a[i] = i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an Array with the length of your `for loop` divided by `2`, as you getting the Reminder of the value of **`i/2`** which will give you half of the values of `i`:

```
int length = 10;
int arr_i[] = new int[(int)(length/2)];
int index = 0;
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
  if((i%2) == 0){
    arr[index] = i;
    index ++;
  }
}
```